# incorporating measurement uncertainty in comparison of paired observations

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Apologies if this is obvious.

I have six paired observations, before and after an event. I want to determine if the results indicate a statistical change but include the measurement uncertainty, not just the measurement variance.

Without the measurement uncertainty, I would do a paired student's t-test. Can someone point me in the right direction for including uncertainty?

Comment: What is "measurement uncertainty"?

Comment: I'm referring to systematic error due to the limitations of the measurement apparatus. Per IEC (international electrotechnical comission) standards, this would be the 'Type B' uncertainty. (Eg. precision of balance/ruler/oscilloscope/etc.)

Comment: If this measurement error is independent of the measured quantity $(X)$ and its expectations is $0$, then it only affects the variance of the sample average of $X_{\text{after}}-X_{\text{before}}$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Thank you. My smallest p-value was 0.0678. Does this render my **bold** statement, below, false?

With a 95% confidence interval, there was not statistical evidence to reject the premise that any of these values were not drawn from a distribution with an equal mean before and after X. Accordingly, there is no evidence that Y changed the Z output. **This statistical conclusion does not include the measurement uncertainty which would only serve to decrease the confidence in being able to claim that there was statistical evidence to separate these paired observations.**

Comment: also...if you give me an answer, I'd love to mark it correct!

Comment: It is a pretty small $p$-value with just $6$ observations and measurement error :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that there likely is a difference between the two sets of observations? The rest of the p-values range from 0.14-0.89.